# Cronjob to periodically refresh cache for django view

Tags: python, django, cron, memcached

I've had some trouble trying to reset my cache every hour for a particular django view.

Right now, I am using the cache_page decorator to cache my view using Memcached. But the cache expires after a while and the request is  uncached from some users.

@cache_page(3600)
def my_view(request):
     ...

How do I write my own django manage.py command to refresh my cache for this view every hour from cron?

In other words, what do I put in my refresh_cache.py file mentioned in the answer here:
[Django caching - can it be done pre-emptively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797773/django-caching-can-it-be-done-pre-emptively?rq=1)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app, you can create a folder called `management` which contains another folder `commands` and an empty `__init__.py` file. Inside `commands` you create another `__init__.py` and a file where you write your custom command. Let's called it `refresh.py`:

```
# refresh.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from main.models import * # You may want to import your models in order to use  
                          # them in your cron job.

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Posts popular threads'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
    # Code to refresh cache
```

Now you can add this file to your cron jobs. You can take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) but basically you use crontab -e to edit your cron jobs and crontab -l to see which cron jobs are running.

You can find all of this and more in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. But could you please tell me what goes in the "#code to refresh cache". How do I call the view and set the response to cache using cache.set()

Comment: You don't call the view. Instead, you add the part that does the refreshing. This is because the view may be doing something else that you don't want in a cron job. As for the specifics, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-low-level-cache-api

Comment: what if i would like to cache my whole view (it's my homepage)? How would I set the cache to response of the whole view from the handle function in refresh.py?

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest that cache_page doesn't cache the whole view, that is, every single process, but only its output. If that is true, you can get rid of this output calling .delete(). Add a prefix to your cached view and explore what keys are being used so you know exactly what to delete. As per a "delete cached view" command, I don't know if that exists.

Comment: Uhm... this can be helpful to you https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5815. Actually, there are several solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268417/expire-a-view-cache-in-django

Comment: thanks Robert! This just became too complex (for me) to figure out right now. So I am going to manually cache the database lookup in my view rather than the whole view as u previously suggested

Answer (score 1):

I want to expand on Roberts answer to fill out the `# Code to refresh cache`

Timezome+location make caches much hard to work with, in my case I just disabled them, also I am not sure about using the test methods in the application code, but it seems to work nicely.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.conf import settings

from ladder.models import Season
from ladder.views import season as season_view


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Refreshes cached pages'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        """
        Script that calls all season pages to refresh the cache on them if it has expired.

        Any time/date settings create postfixes on the caching key, for now the solution is to disable them.
        """

        if settings.USE_I18N:
            raise CommandError('USE_I18N in settings must be disabled.')

        if settings.USE_L10N:
            raise CommandError('USE_L10N in settings must be disabled.')

        if settings.USE_TZ:
            raise CommandError('USE_TZ in settings must be disabled.')

        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        seasons = Season.objects.all()
        for season in seasons:
            path = '/' + season.end_date.year.__str__() + '/round/' + season.season_round.__str__() + '/'
            # use the request factory to generate the correct url for the cache hash
            request = self.factory.get(path)

            season_view(request, season.end_date.year, season.season_round)
            self.stdout.write('Successfully refreshed: %s' % path)
```